# I can't manage to config purgeCSS to look into JSON files for Tailwindcss selectors

Tags: json, nuxtjs

I'm working on a Nuxt.js with netlifyCMS.

When i add a new post to my website, trought netlifyCMS, there is a new json file with all the content of this post added to the project.
In this json, I have some tailwindcss selectors.

My issue : In production build, i can't manage to purgeCSS don't remove tailwindcss selectors used.

I'm working with tailwindcss from somes month now, and i have no issue with html, js or css files.

Thanks for your help.